# Display coordinates separated by period on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: csv, datatable, coordinates, arcgis

I need to export a CSV file with points and coordinates from ArcGIS Pro, which displays coordinates separated by ",". (E.g. 39,8898) This creates a problem when trying to process the data in R, which recognises columns separated by ",".

How do I change the display of the coordinates in the ArcGIS table to use "." instead of ","?

Answer (score 0):

A simple constraint with the software. You can duplicate the Values into another field, and use a search + replace ("," replaced with ".").

However, if you're using a CSV Table correctly, you should be limited to 60,000 some rows. So, you can open up the CSV in excel and do a search and replace in there, both work.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I tried both "Find and replace" and the replace() function on ArcGIS but it doesn't work on X,Y columns. I also tried to replace them afterwords but on a csv file when I choose to replace the "," to a "." it replaces all ","; so there is na column separation any more